# How to prove that a language $A$ is decidable?

Tags: formal-languages, proof-techniques, decision-problem

How to prove: A language $A$ is decidable $\Leftrightarrow$ if there is a turing machine which lists $A$ in a word length alphabetically ordering.

Word length alphabetically means a sorting first after the word length and then after the character ordering $(\epsilon,a,b,aa,ab,ba,bb, ...)$.

Hope somebody can help me like give a hint or an approach.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: I said I hope somebody can help that doesn't mean that I want you to solve the task.. ?!?! If I  ask something on StackExchange I ALWAYS want to have a hint or an approach.

Comment: Hint: ​ The result is not constructive; you'll have a different decider for each possible number of elements in $A$. ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write $L$ for the language, $\mathscr{A}$ for the alphabet and $\mathscr{A}^*$ for the set of all possible words.

If $L$ is decidable, then it's easy to list the words in $L$ in any order that doesn't depend on $L$, such as length-then-lexicographic order: list all the words in $\mathscr{A}$, and for each word, test whether it's in $L$ and output the word only if it is in $L$.

Conversely, suppose that there is a Turing machine $M$ that lists the words in $A$ in length-then-lexicographic order. By definition, this shows that $L$ is recursively enumerable. How can you go from this to the stronger property that $L$ is decidable?

The idea is that you can turn this into a decision procedure if you know when to stop. That is to stay, to decide whether a word $w$ is in $L$, stop the machine after $s$ steps. $s$ may depend on $w$ — if it doesn't, that means that $L$ can be recognized by a finite-state machine — so I'll write $s(w)$. If $w$ has been listed then $w \in L$ by assumption about the machine $M$, and if $w$ has not been listen then $w \notin L$ by construction of $s(w)$.

Of course, in general, there is no suitable function $s$: if $L$ is recursively enumerable but not decidable, that means that no computable function $s$ exists.

Use the fact that the order is length-then-lexicographic to find a suitable function $s$. There's a subtlety there: the function $s$ itself might not be computable — but it can be expressed in terms of how $M$ runs. The important point is that you can construct a machine $M'$ which runs $M$ for time and decides when to stop based on the output of $M$ and on some extra counter.

Comment: The phrase "describe a way to compute it" suggest that we can actually compute it, however we can't. If $L$ is finite then we can wait forever for the next word to appear but at some moment it won't. That means that for finite $L$ we have to "know" the size of the set to conclude the output is finished. Unfortunately we cannot compute that size of $L$, but assuming the size is known we fix the algorithm for the decider. In short: the decider exists, but in cannot be computed (in general).

Comment: @HendrikJan True, my formulation was inadequate. The *decider machine* can be computed from $M$, but the number $s$ can't be (it depends on how long $M$ runs to list each word).

Comment: It seems it is a little more complicated. When $L$ is infinite, then we know how to do the decider: we wait until the enumerator shows either $w$ or a string later than $w$, which will always happen. If $L$ is finite then we cannot use that construction. There will be no next word after some point and we cannot conclude we have seen the last one *unless* the number of elements of $L$ is known. Thus the decider exists, but we only know which one it is when we know the cardinality of $L$. It cannot be computed.

Comment: @HendrikJan. Very good point. Too bad we can't give more than one upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You know that a language $L$ is decidable if there is a TM, $M$ which when given a word $w$ as input always halts and accepts if $w\in L$ or halts and rejects if $w\notin L$. Here are some hints to get you started.

($\Rightarrow$) This is easy. If $L$ is decidable by a TM $D$, you can make an enumerator TM $E$ by trying all possible inputs in order. For word $w_i$ in that order $E$ will run $M$ on $w_i$ and write $w_i$ if $M$ accepts.

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose you had an enumerator $E$ that lists all $w\in L$ in lexicographic order. Use that to construct a decider $M$ which when given $w$ as input, runs $E$ until it finds $w$ among the enumerated strings or fails to find $w$. Your task is to show that it will always either find $w$ or decides it does not appear on the enumeration in a finite amount of time.